# WARNING: Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... failed id=1515 responseStatus=500 Internal Server Error status=500

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using Gitlab self server community version ci/cd function, It has been running well, But suddenly one day,All the projects in the gitlab/cicd has failed, it mentions below errors:

```
Uploading artifacts for successful job
Uploading artifacts...
promotion-api/my-boot-module-system/target/*.jar: found 1 matching files and directories 
WARNING: Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... failed  id=1515 responseStatus=500 Internal Server Error status=500 token=xrDFnLeB
WARNING: Retrying...                                context=artifacts-uploader error=invalid argument
WARNING: Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... failed  id=1515 responseStatus=500 Internal Server Error status=500 token=xrDFnLeB
WARNING: Retrying...                                context=artifacts-uploader error=invalid argument
WARNING: Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... failed  id=1515 responseStatus=500 Internal Server Error status=500 token=xrDFnLeB
FATAL: invalid argument                            
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Below is the code in .gitlab-ci.yml

```
deploy-java:
  stage: deploy
  dependencies:
    - build-java
  image:
    name: docker/compose:latest
  before_script:
    - docker info
    - docker-compose -v
  script:
    - cd promotion-api
    - docker-compose build
    - docker images
    - docker ps -a
    - docker-compose up -d
  tags:
    - promotion
```

2021-3-29:

I switched the runner from linux version to docker, seems all fine till now

Comment: This problem sometimes occurs and sometimes disappears, it seems to be related to the frequency of CI/CD

Comment: Was this previously building OK? If so, roll back the code to the last successful build point, and do your customer demo at that point.

Comment: In `responseStatus=500 Internal Server Error status=500`, what service is being contacted - is that a GitLab service to upload build artifacts? If this is a service that is under GitLab's control then you should report the server error to them.

Comment: @halfer The error is occured from gitlab server, It is built successfully before, It happens sometimes, Not so often. Is it possible to ignore to upload artifacts ? It is really no useful for me ...

Comment: Ah, is this an instance run by GitLab, or is it self-hosted?

Comment: @halfer self-hosted community version

Comment: Aha - please make a note of that in your post. That is probably quite relevant!

Comment: Have you looked through GitLab's bug tracker? Perhaps someone has encountered it before.

Comment: @halfer sure definitely, I just modied the question text, I switch the runner to docker version, seems all fine till now

Answer (score 6):

For me the problem was that gitlab had run out of disk-space. 
After having deleted unnecessary artifacts and files everything was working correctly again.

You can check your system status (if you host your own gitlab) here: [www.gitlab-url.com/admin/system_info](http://www.gitlab-url.com/admin/system_info) 
(Go to: *Admin Area > Monitoring > System Info*)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You ran into a bug in GitLab itself. Instead of a rather obscure HTTP status 500 it should say what the issue is explicitly. It is likely not a problem in your repository or CI settings.

Follow these issues to find out more:

- Artifact is stopped in the transfer, possibly because it takes longer than some timeout to upload: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/26869
- Artifact is larger than 1 GB: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/267111